Pytesseract wrong text recognition when word are close to each other
When I use PyTesseract to recognize the text in this image, it returns 'FORREST C. BLopGetTrT' instead of FORREST C. BLODGETT The result of code i get
the image i use, which contains many name.
I suspect the letters are too close to each other and the image have capital letters in different size. I tried increasing the size of the image, but it did not work well. The case (uppercase or lowercase) does not matter here. Is there any way to fix the issue and get the correct name?
my code
from pytesseract import image_to_string
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("textimg.png")
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
img = cv2.resize(img, (w*20, h*20))
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = image_to_string(thr, lang="eng")
print(txt)

I tried increasing the size of the image, but it did not work well.

I would guess the problem is that the names are written in smallcaps, i.e. they have capital letters in different sizes, and tesseract doesn't handle that well. Perhaps some training is in order

@johnnyaug Thanks for reply. Yes i  think smallcaps is the problem. Do you know how to do training with  PyTesseract?

tesseract v88Iu3Co.png - --psm 6 produces the following output:
General Economics; including Economic Theory
History of Thought, Methodology,
Economic History, and Economic Systems

Lerry D. ANDERsON, Ph.D. Northwestern 1980. The
diffusion of technology in the nineteenth-century
American city: Municipal water supply investments.

KAZUHIRO ARAL, Ph.D. Illinois 1979. Expected cost-
minimizing search and expected utility-maximizing
search.

Yves M. BaLcer, Ph.D. Massachusetts Institute of
Technology 1980. Four essays in economics of un-
certainty.

PAULINA BEATO, Ph.D. Minnesota 1979. Marginal cost
pricing and increasing returns.

BmMAL K. Beri, Ph.D. Johns Hopkins 1980. A study of
problems associated with transfer of wealth under
conditions of uncertainty.

GAUTAM BHATTACHARYA, Ph.D. Rochester 1980. Two
essays in economics of uncertainty: The importance
of learning in planning with exhaustible resources
and optimality of equilibium with incomplete
markets.

Forrest C. BLODGETT, Ph.D. Portland State 1979.
Institutional economics and urban political econ-
omy.

Km C. BORDER, Ph.D. Minnesota 1979. Social welfare
functions and large economies.

RANDALL L. CaLvert, Ph.D. California Institute of
Technology 1980. On the role of imperfect informa-
tion in electoral politics.

ANN M. Carros, Ph.D. Western Ontario 1980. The
North American fur trade, 1804-21: A study in the
life cycle of a duopoly.

JEFFREY CARMICHAEL, Ph.D. Princeton 1979. The role
of government financial policy in economic growth.

THomas H. CaTe, Ph.D. Florida State 1979. The intel-
lectual origins of John Maynard Keynes’ policy rec-
ommendations.

TERRY CHACON, Ph.D. California (San Diego) 1979.
Public employment in a macro-economic model.

SHEETAL K. CHAND, Ph.D. Western Ontario 1980. In-
flation, unemployment, and neoclassical monetary
equilibrium.

HeNry W. CHAPPELL, Ph.D. Yale 1979. The economics
of campaign finance: An empirical study.

ADHIP CHAUDHURI, Ph.D. Columbia 1980. Envy, dis-
tributive justice, and social choice.

BARRY S. CLARK, Ph.D. Massachusetts 1980. Justice
and economic theory.


Hi user898678, i try to use txt = image_to_string("textimg.png", config='--psm 6')
print(txt)
but i still get Letry D. ANDERSON instaed of Lerry D. ANDERsON. Can i check how to set up psm?

If you face OCR problem with 's' vs 'S' (or 'w' vs 'W', 'o' vs 'O') you can not fix it easily with pytesseract.  With tesseract API (c++ or C) you can try the trick of recognizing the same image 2-3 times without cleaning the internal settings, but it does not work with tesseract executable (and therefor with pytesseract). Another solution is to OCR allcaps words separately.
